# Отключение сетевого интерфейса в VMware

Tags: vmware

Как можно автоматизировать включение/выключения интерфейса в VMware. Интересует действия не в самой гостевой ОС а именно в виртуальной машине. wmrun.exe такого не умеет делать.

Если не в VMware, то с какой ВМ можно получить интерфейс для управления запущенной Гостевой ОС.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем именно в виртуальной машине? Ведь адаптеры самой виртуальной машины представляют из себя такие же сетевые карты, как и обычные (ну только виртуальные). И отображаются они в "Сетевые подключения" и управляются также как обычные. Например, ваш виртуальный адаптер имеет имя "WMWare Net1", значит чтобы выключить его используем команду

```
netsh interface set interface name="WMWare Net1" admin=DISABLED
```

а чтобы включить

```
netsh interface set interface name="WMWare Net1" admin=ENABLED
```

Answer (score 1):

подключения к серверу...

```
$erver = Connect-VIServer -Server $esxHost -Credential $esxCredential -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue

# external network name
$networkName= "VM Network"
#вызов самой функции     
VMware.DisconnectNetworkAdapter $vmName $server $networkName
```

p.s. не забудь добавить `Add-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core`

```
function GetNetworkAdapter
{
    Param
    ( 
        $vmName, 
        $server = $server,
        $networkName
    )

    if(!$server)
    { 
        $server = $global:DefaultVIServer 
    }

    Clear-Variable vm -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $vm = Get-VM -Name $vmName -Server $server -ErrorAction:Stop
    return ( (Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm -Server $server -ErrorAction:Stop)|?{$_.NetworkName -like $networkName} )
}



function ConnectNetworkAdapter
{
    Param
    ( 
        $vmName, 
        $server = $server,
        $networkName 
    )


    if(!$server)
    {
        $server = $global:DefaultVIServer
    }   

    #adding new network adamter
    Clear-Variable networkAdapter -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $networkAdapter = GetNetworkAdapter $vmName $server $networkName

    if (!$networkAdapter)
    {
        return $false
    }

    Clear-Variable macAddr -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $macAddr = [string]$networkAdapter.MacAddress

    Clear-Variable res -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $res = Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkAdapter $networkAdapter -StartConnected $true -Confirm:$false
    if ($res)
    {
        if((Get-VM $vmName).powerstate -eq "poweredon")
        {
            Clear-Variable res1 -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
            $res1 = Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkAdapter $networkAdapter -Connected $true -Confirm:$false
            if ($res1)
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
        return $true
    }
    Write-ErrorLog "Could connect network adapter for $networkName to VM $vmName"
    return $false
}



function DisconnectNetworkAdapter
{
    Param
    ( 
        $vmName, 
        $server = $server,
        $networkName 
    )


    if(!$server)
    {
        $server = $global:DefaultVIServer
    }

    #adding new network adamter
    Clear-Variable networkAdapter -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $networkAdapter = GetNetworkAdapter $vmName $server $networkName
    if (!$networkAdapter)
    {
        return $false
    }

    Clear-Variable macAddr -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $macAddr = [string]$networkAdapter.MacAddress

    Clear-Variable res -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $res = Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkAdapter $networkAdapter -StartConnected $false -Confirm:$false
    if ($res)
    {
        if((Get-VM $vmName).powerstate -eq "poweredon")
        {
            Clear-Variable res1 -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
            $res1 = Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkAdapter $networkAdapter -Connected $false -Confirm:$false
            if ($res1)
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
        return $true
    }
    Write-ErrorLog "Could disconnect network adapter for $networkName to VM $vmName"
    return $false
}
```